# Unknown column but colum exists in view

Tags: mysql, error-code

I have created a view which contains field 'Spieltag'. Here you can see my view...

```
   CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `auswärtsergebnisse` AS
    SELECT 
        `bundesligaergebnisse`.`Spieltag` AS `Spieltag`,
        `bundesligaergebnisse`.`Heimteam` AS `Heimteam`,
        `bundesligaergebnisse`.`Heimtore` AS `Heimtore`
    FROM
        `bundesligaergebnisse`
```

But when I run `SELECT Spieltag FROM analytics.auswärtsergebnisse;`
I get Error Code 1054, Unknown field 'Spieltag' in 'field list'. With Heimteam and Heimtore is everything fine and select * works fine.

Comment: I am unclear what the view has to do with the query in error. Your view is called `heimergebnisse` but you are querying auswärtsergebnisse

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the wrong name of the view, now it's correct.

Comment: There cannot be a column called `Spieltag` in `bundesligaergebnisse`.